# How to set ggboxplot mean_sd shape according to a factor?

Tags: r, shapes, boxplot, ggpubr

I'm trying to represent a multivariate dataset with one of the variables having 25 factors using different shapes (ggplot2 has this many shapes available).
I'll use the *iris* dataset as a reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
data(iris)

iris_pivot <- pivot_longer(iris, col = 1:4, names_to = "parameter")

ggboxplot(data = iris_pivot, x = "parameter", y = "value",
    add = "mean_sd", add.params = list(color = "Species"),
     legend = c("right"))
```

Which results in the following plot
[image: boxplot of 4 different parameters, with the average by a factor with 3 levels]

I have tried setting the shape in *add.parameter* and using `scale_shape_manual` without success.

```
ggboxplot(data = iris_pivot, x = "parameter", y = "value",
add = "mean_sd", add.params = list(color = "Species", shape = "Species"), legend = c("right"))
```

All help is appreciated even if it doesn't use *ggpubr*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `aes(shape = Species)` to the linerange layer:

```r
p <- ggboxplot(data = iris_pivot, x = "parameter", y = "value",
          add = "mean_sd", add.params = list(color = "Species",
                                             size = 1),
          legend = c("right")) 

p$layers[[2]]$mapping <- aes(colour = Species, shape = Species)

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to also select the shapes?

Comment: @SaraEsteves yes - add a `+ scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 2, 3))` or whatever numbers you like

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that I get only one mean_sd point. I'll look more into it